# SQL error: misuse of aggregate

Tags: sql, sqlite

SQLite version 3.4.0
What's wrong with aggregate functions? Additionally, I suspect that ORDER BY won't work as well. How to rewrite this?

```
sqlite> SELECT p1.domain_id, p2.domain_id, COUNT(p1.domain_id) AS d1, COUNT(p2.domain_id) AS d2
   ...> FROM PDB as p1, Interacting_PDBs as i1, PDB as p2, Interacting_PDBs as i2
   ...> WHERE p1.id = i1.PDB_first_id
   ...> AND p2.id = i2.PDB_second_id
   ...> AND i1.id = i2.id
   ...> AND d1>100
   ...> AND d2>100
   ...> ORDER BY d1, d2;
SQL error: misuse of aggregate: 
sqlite>
```

Answer (score 97, accepted):

When using an aggregate function (sum / count / ... ), you also have to make use of the GROUP BY clause.

Next to that, when you want to filter on the result of an aggregate , you cannot do that in the WHERE clause, but you have to do that in the HAVING clause.

```
SELECT p1.domain_id, p2.domain_id, COUNT(p1.domain_id) AS d1, COUNT(p2.domain_id) AS d2
    FROM PDB as p1, Interacting_PDBs as i1, PDB as p2, Interacting_PDBs as i2
    WHERE p1.id = i1.PDB_first_id
    AND p2.id = i2.PDB_second_id
    AND i1.id = i2.id
GROUP BY p1.domain_Id, p2.domain_Id
HAVING d1 > 100 AND d2 > 100
ORDER BY d1, d2;
```

Comment: +1 I guess the use of aggregate functions without a proper GROUP BY clause is rooted in bad habits carried over from MySQL...

Comment: this answer saved me many minutes trying to remember the syntax, and it came with an easy to understand explanation.  Cheers @Frederik

Comment: Having is not filtering out the columns for me!

Comment: `"SELECT *, group_concat(" + TABLE_SUBJECT + "."+COLUMN_TYPE + ") AS type, 
     + "FROM " + TABLE_STUDENT + " "
     + "INNER JOIN " + TABLE_SUBJECT + " ON "
     +  TABLE_STUDENT + "." + COLUMN_ID + " = " +   TABLE_SUBJECT + "." 

     + COLUMN_STUDENT_ID + " WHERE " +  TABLE_STUDENT + "." + COLUMN_ID + " = 

3 "
     + "GROUP BY TABLE_SUBJECT + "." + COLUMN_STUDENT_ID
     + "HAVING type = " MATH " 
     + "OR type = ENGLISH";`

Comment: This is my query but the result also contains the 3rd subject while i only want the above 2. Can you please help?

Answer (score 13):

Short-version fix for this is:

When you're using function like `COUNT/SUM`, you need to use `HAVING` instead of `WHERE`.

Comment: You are right, but why? I tried filtering out some data with an aggregate function inside 'WHERE' clause; however it did not work. It only worked with 'HAVING' clause. Is there any particular reason?

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure that you don't use one of the columns that you are using COUNT/SUM for a WHERE clause. Make sure you use HAVING instead of WHERE for those variables.