# SQLite Misuse of aggregate: SUM()

Tags: sql, sqlite

What is wrong about this SQL command, please?

```
SELECT DISTINCT email_to FROM emails WHERE email_box='SENT' ORDER BY SUM(email_to)
```

I have a table `emails`.
Two of the fields are `email_to` **(contains a email recipient address string)**, and `email_box` which indicates if an `email` is stored in `INBOX`, `OUTBOX` or `SENT`.

I would now like to get all `email_to's`, order by the frequency of their occurance in the table.

I don't know why I am getting the `misuse of aggregate` error. I would also like to ask how to fix it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL error: misuse of aggregate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/648083/sql-error-misuse-of-aggregate)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The field in an order by statement is evaluated after the select statement.  This means it can only reference fields which are in the select statement already. Try:

```
SELECT email_to, count(*) as total_emails FROM emails WHERE email_box='SENT' group by email_to ORDER BY total_emails
```

In the above query, the order by statement is able to reference the count of appearances with the field "total_emails".

Comment: And about the "DISTINCT"?

Comment: `Group By` only returns one of each.  `Distinct` is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

This is your query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT email_to
FROM emails
WHERE email_box = 'SENT'
ORDER BY SUM(email_to);
```

The `SUM()` suggests an aggregation query, but this isn't an aggregation.  You can fix this by using `group by` instead:

```
SELECT email_to
FROM emails
WHERE email_box = 'SENT'
GROUP BY email_to
ORDER BY SUM(email_to);
```

However, I doubt that `email_to` is actually a number.  If you want the ordering by the *count*, then use `count()`:

```
SELECT email_to
FROM emails
WHERE email_box = 'SENT'
GROUP BY email_to
ORDER BY COUNT(*);
```