# relational division

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sqlite, relational-division

I'm supposed to write a query for this statement:

> List the names of customers, and album titles, for cases where the customer has bought the entire album (i.e. all tracks in the album)

I know that I should use division.

Here is my answer but I get some weird syntax errors that I can't resolve.

```
SELECT 
     R1.FirstName
     ,R1.LastName
     ,R1.Title
FROM (Customer C, Invoice I, InvoiceLine IL, Track T, Album Al) AS R1
WHERE 
     C.CustomerId=I.CustomerId 
     AND I.InvoiceId=IL.InvoiceId
     AND T.TrackId=IL.TrackId 
     AND Al.AlbumId=T.AlbumId
     AND NOT EXISTS ( 
          SELECT 
               R2.Title
           FROM (Album Al, Track T) AS R2
           WHERE 
                T.AlbumId=Al.AlbumId
                AND R2.Title NOT IN (
                    SELECT R3.Title
                    FROM (Album Al, Track T) AS R3
                    WHERE 
                        COUNT(R1.TrackId)=COUNT(R3.TrackId)
                )
     );
```

ERROR: `misuse of aggregate function COUNT()`

You can find the schema for the database [here](https://chinookdatabase.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Chinook_Schema&referringTitle=Documentation)

Comment: You're missing a closed parenthesis at the very end.  (Two open subqueries, one closing parenthesis)

Comment: `( SELECT R2.Title
    FROM (Album Al, Track T) AS R2` looks wiered to me.  are you intending to do a cross join between album and track?

Comment: I fixed the parenthesis, but I still get this error now `misuse of aggregate function COUNT()` @Aaron D

Comment: Yes I am. There is no problem in that line. I've tested it in other queries. @xQbert

Comment: Why use division?  You're approach seems overly complex.  Produce two sets of data: 1 listing all tracks per album along with a count, another listing a count of tracks a user has purchased per album, compare the two totals, if they match then they've bought them all.  Just my 2cents

Comment: I tried using `INTERSECT`. I'm getting the correct answer but in that query I can't get the names of customers in the result. @ xQbert

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/648083/sql-error-misuse-of-aggregate

Comment: In your DB, can a person buy the same Track more than once? If yes, then you may need to rethink your methodology, because in that case Count (Tracks I bought) could equal or even exceed Count (Tracks on Album) without me having bought the entire album.

Comment: No, obviously they can't but the same track twice. It wouldn't make sense. @jdg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot alias a table list such as `(Album Al, Track T)` which is an out-dated syntax for `(Album Al CROSS JOIN Track T)`. You can either alias a table, e.g. `Album Al` or a subquery, e.g. `(SELECT * FROM Album CROSS JOIN Track) AS R2`.

So first of all you should get your joins straight. I don't assume that you are being taught those old comma-separated joins, but got them from some old book or Website? Use proper explicit joins instead.

Then you cannot use `WHERE COUNT(R1.TrackId) = COUNT(R3.TrackId)`. `COUNT` is an aggregate function and aggregation is done after `WHERE`.

As to the query: It's a good idea to compare track counts. So let's do that step by step.

Query to get the track count per album:

```
select albumid, count(*)
from track
group by albumid;
```

Query to get the track count per customer and album:

```
select i.customerid, t.albumid, count(distinct t.trackid)
from track t
join invoiceline il on il.trackid = t.trackid
join invoice i on i.invoiceid = il.invoiceid
group by i.customerid, t.albumid;
```

Complete query:

```
select c.firstname, c.lastname, a.title
from
(
  select i.customerid, t.albumid, count(distinct t.trackid) as cnt
  from track t
  join invoiceline il on il.trackid = t.trackid
  join invoice i on i.invoiceid = il.invoiceid
  group by i.customerid, t.albumid
) bought
join
(
  select albumid, count(*) as cnt
  from track
  group by albumid
) complete on complete.albumid = bought.albumid and complete.cnt = bought.cnt
join customer c on c.customerid = bought.customerid
join album a on a.albumid = bought.albumid;
```

Comment: I like the way you approach the problem. I run the query but I get `ambiguous column name: trackid:` @thorsten-kettner

Comment: I corrected that by adding t.trackid. now I'm getting `no such column: c.firstname`

Comment: Right, I forgot the qualifier for trackid. But as to c.firstname I am out of clues. We join the table customer, call this c and select its column firstname. Or doesn't that column exist? Is it a typo maybe in your query already and the real name is first_name or the like? Check the customer table if there is a column with that name.

Comment: There's in an extra `;` in `complete.cnt = bought.cnt;` it should be removed. After that it works just fine.

Comment: Ah, sorry about that. I'm glad my query works now for you.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you are using count in the wrong place

use having for aggregate function

```
 SELECT R3.Title
    FROM (Album Al, Track T) AS R3
    HAVING  COUNT(R1.TrackId)=COUNT(R3.TrackId))
```

but be sure of alias  because in some database the alias in not available in subquery ..

Comment: Well spotted, but that still won't work. As the track IDs are not null of course, `HAVING COUNT(R1.TrackId) = COUNT(R3.TrackId)` is equal to `HAVING COUNT(*) = COUNT(*)` which in turn is equal to not having a `HAVING` clause at all.

Answer (score 0):

You should simplify your query. Take a look at this:

```
SELECT FirstName
    , LastName
    , Title
FROM (
    SELECT C.FirstName
         , C.LastName
         , A.AlbumID
         , A.Title
         , COUNT(DISTINCT TrackID) as TracksInvoiced
    FROM Customer C
    INNER JOIN Invoice I
    ON I.CustomerId = C.CustomerId
    INNER JOIN InvoiceLine IL
    ON I.InvoiceId = IL.InvoiceId
    INNER JOIN Track T 
    ON T.TrackID = I
    INNER JOIN Album A 
    ON A.AlbumID = T.AlbumID
    GROUP BY C.FirstName, C.LastName, A.AlbumID, A.Title
) C
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT AlbumID
        , COUNT(TrackID) as TotalTracks
    FROM Track
    GROUP BY AlbumID
) A
ON C.AlbumID = A.AlbumID
AND TracksInvoiced = TotalTracks
```

I used two subselects, the first one counts invoiced tracks per customer and album and joins it with another subselect for each album and amount of tracks on it, only where the two counts are equal.

Answer (score 0):

This one seems to be a little less complicated:

```sql
SELECT r.FirstName, r.LastName, r.Title FROM
(
    SELECT C.FirstName as FirstName,
           C.LastName as LastName,
           A.Title as Title,
           A.AlbumId as AlbumId,
           COUNT(*) as count
    FROM Customer C, Invoice I, InvoiceLine IL, Track T, Album A
    WHERE C.CustomerId=I.CustomerId
      AND I.InvoiceId = IL.InvoiceId
      AND T.TrackId   = IL.TrackId
      AND A.AlbumId   = T.AlbumId
    GROUP BY C.CustomerId, A.AlbumId
) AS r
WHERE r.count IS IN
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Track T
    WHERE T.AlbumId = r.AlbumId
)
```

Tested the idea on a simpler basis and extended to your example so I don't give a guarantee that you can copy and paste and its working immediately...

Comment: Your query is not correct. You are missing `A.AlbumId` in your `GROUP BY` clause. And you shouldn't use correlated `IN` clauses. Use either a correlated `EXISTS` or a non-correlated `IN` so as not to confuse the reader. The join to Album in the `IN` clause is superfluous by the way.

Comment: Thanks for the clues - could not try the query, was intended as hint to find a solution as long as no better answers existed...