# Sequelize complains "misuse of aggregate: SUM()" when using double vs single quotes in raw query

Tags: sql, node.js, sqlite, sequelize.js

When I run this query in [DB Browser for SQLite](http://sqlitebrowser.org/):

```
SELECT week
, SUM (CASE when activityType = 'rockclimbing' then elapsedTime else 0 END) AS rockclimbing
, SUM (CASE when activityType = 'hike' then elapsedTime else 0 END) AS hike
, SUM (CASE when activityType = 'run' then elapsedTime else 0 END) AS run
FROM activity
WHERE year=2016
AND activityType IN ('rockclimbing', 'hike', 'run')
GROUP BY week
ORDER BY week;
```

It returns the data that I am looking for:

```
week rockclimbing hike run

"1" "0" "0" "2.09"

"2" "0" "0" "4.63"

"3" "0" "0" "7.22"

"4" "0" "0" "2.94"

"5" "0" "0" "5.59"
```

(Ignore the "quotes". SO copy/pasted the data with them included.)

However, when I pass this query to Sequelize using .query() I get the error: `misuse of aggregate: SUM()`

Here is my Sequelize code:

`sequelize.query('SELECT week, SUM (CASE when activityType = "rockclimbing" then elapsedTime else 0 END) AS rockclimbing, SUM (CASE when activityType = "hike" then elapsedTime else 0 END) AS hike, SUM (CASE when activityType = "run" then elapsedTime else 0 END) AS run FROM activity WHERE year=2016 AND activityType IN ("rockclimbing", "hike", "run") GROUP BY week ORDER BY week;', { model: Activity }).then(...etc..).catch(...etc...);`

Here is the query as generated by Sequelize and output in my console:

`Executing (default): SELECT week, SUM (CASE when activityType = "rockclimbing" then elapsedTime else 0 END) AS rockclimbing, SUM (CASE when activityType = "hike" then elapsedTime else 0 END) AS hike, SUM (CASE when activityType = "run" then elapsedTime else 0 END) AS run FROM activity WHERE year=2016 AND activityType IN ("rockclimbing", "hike", "run") GROUP BY week ORDER BY week;`

My JavaScript `.catch()`s errors and logs them to the console:

```
.catch(function(err) {
  console.log('Error! ', err);
});
```

So I see this error object logged out to my console:

```
{ SequelizeDatabaseError: SQLITE_ERROR: misuse of aggregate: SUM()
    at Query.formatError (/xxx/xxx/project_name/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/sqlite/query.js:348:14)
    at afterExecute (/xxx/xxx/project_name/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/sqlite/query.js:112:29)
    at replacement (/xxx/xxx/project_name/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/trace.js:19:31)
    at Statement.errBack (/xxx/xxx/project_name/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/sqlite3.js:16:21)
  name: 'SequelizeDatabaseError',
  message: 'SQLITE_ERROR: misuse of aggregate: SUM()',
  parent: 
   { Error: SQLITE_ERROR: misuse of aggregate: SUM()
       at Error (native)
     errno: 1,
     code: 'SQLITE_ERROR',
     sql: 'SELECT week, SUM (CASE when activityType = "rockclimbing" then elapsedTime else 0 END) AS rockclimbing, SUM (CASE when activityType = "hike" then elapsedTime else 0 END) AS hike, SUM (CASE when activityType = "run" then elapsedTime else 0 END) AS run FROM activity WHERE year=2016 AND activityType IN ("rockclimbing", "hike", "run") GROUP BY week ORDER BY week;' },
  original: 
   { Error: SQLITE_ERROR: misuse of aggregate: SUM()
       at Error (native)
     errno: 1,
     code: 'SQLITE_ERROR',
     sql: 'SELECT week, SUM (CASE when activityType = "rockclimbing" then elapsedTime else 0 END) AS rockclimbing, SUM (CASE when activityType = "hike" then elapsedTime else 0 END) AS hike, SUM (CASE when activityType = "run" then elapsedTime else 0 END) AS run FROM activity WHERE year=2016 AND activityType IN ("rockclimbing", "hike", "run") GROUP BY week ORDER BY week;' },
  sql: 'SELECT week, SUM (CASE when activityType = "rockclimbing" then elapsedTime else 0 END) AS rockclimbing, SUM (CASE when activityType = "hike" then elapsedTime else 0 END) AS hike, SUM (CASE when activityType = "run" then elapsedTime else 0 END) AS run FROM activity WHERE year=2016 AND activityType IN ("rockclimbing", "hike", "run") GROUP BY week ORDER BY week;' }
```

What is the problem here? Why does this query work in DB Browser but not in my app?

I did search the Internet and Stackoverflow before posting this question. While [some questions did touch on my issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/648083/sql-error-misuse-of-aggregate) none of the suggestions/solutions helped me/worked when I tried them.

Comment: You're asking why one query works in SQLite, but another fails in Sequelize? The other one has errors perhaps?

Comment: add activtyType to the select of your DB Browser for SQLLite and see if you get an error... the two statements are not equal.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen they are now the same query, which is why I'm asking why one fails and one works.

Comment: Apologies, I originally posted two _slightly_ different queries which both give the same error anyways. I've edited my question. Also, why the downvote? How could I improve my question?

Comment: @xQbert I added `activityType` to my `select` statement DB Browser did not give me an error. It still give the same error in Sequelize.

Comment: one way to improve your question is to show the output from both sqlite and your javascript. also, include DDL and DML so that we can try to repro.

Comment: @BryanNewman I've edited my question and added the output from SQLite/DB Browser and the console output from Node. If you would like a copy of the database, I'm comfortable sharing the table with you over another channel. Here is a copy of my Sequelize model: https://pastebin.com/JJZT8Ewj Thanks for your help.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a working version, though I can't tell the significant difference between my version and your version except the type of quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few subtle differences here, and one of them is important: I transposed the `'` and `"` characters in the javascript.

```
> Executing (default): SELECT * FROM `activity`
[ { activityType: 'rockclimbing',
    year: 2017,
    week: 1,
    elapsedTime: 1.2345 },
  { activityType: 'rockclimbing',
    year: 2017,
    week: 2,
    elapsedTime: 1.2345 },
  { activityType: 'rockclimbing',
    year: 2017,
    week: 3,
    elapsedTime: 66.45 },
  { activityType: 'hike', year: 2017, week: 1, elapsedTime: 1.2345 },
  { activityType: 'hike',
    year: 2017,
    week: 2,
    elapsedTime: 3.141592 },
  { activityType: 'hike', year: 2017, week: 3, elapsedTime: -1 },
  { activityType: 'hike', year: 2017, week: 4, elapsedTime: 10000 },
  { activityType: 'run', year: 2017, week: 4, elapsedTime: 10 },
  { activityType: 'run', year: 2017, week: 5, elapsedTime: 100 },
  { activityType: 'run', year: 2017, week: 6, elapsedTime: 1000 } ]

> sequelize.query("SELECT week, SUM (CASE when activityType = 'rockclimbing' then elapsedTime else 0 END) AS rockclimbing, SUM (CASE when activityType = 'hike' then elapsedTime else 0 END) AS hike, SUM (CASE when activityType = 'run' then elapsedTime else 0 END) AS run FROM activity     WHERE year=2017 AND activityType IN ('rockclimbing', 'hike', 'run') GROUP BY week ORDER BY week", { type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT}).then(function(activities) {console.log(activities)})
Promise {
  _bitField: 0,
  _fulfillmentHandler0: undefined,
  _rejectionHandler0: undefined,
  _promise0: undefined,
  _receiver0: undefined }
> Executing (default): SELECT week, SUM (CASE when activityType = 'rockclimbing' then elapsedTime else 0 END) AS rockclimbing, SUM (CASE when activityType = 'hike' then elapsedTime else 0 END) AS hike, SUM (CASE when activityType = 'run' then elapsedTime else 0 END) AS run FROM     activity WHERE year=2017 AND activityType IN ('rockclimbing', 'hike', 'run') GROUP BY week ORDER BY week
```

Results:

```
[ { week: 1, rockclimbing: 1.2345, hike: 1.2345, run: 0 },
  { week: 2, rockclimbing: 1.2345, hike: 3.141592, run: 0 },
  { week: 3, rockclimbing: 66.45, hike: -1, run: 0 },
  { week: 4, rockclimbing: 0, hike: 10000, run: 10 },
  { week: 5, rockclimbing: 0, hike: 0, run: 100 },
  { week: 6, rockclimbing: 0, hike: 0, run: 1000 } ]
```

DDL & DML:

```
sqlite> create table activity ( activityType varchar(20), year int, week int, elapsedTime float);
sqlite> insert into activity values ('rockclimbing',2017,1,1.2345);
sqlite> insert into activity values ('rockclimbing',2017,2,1.2345);
sqlite> insert into activity values ('rockclimbing',2017,3,66.45);
sqlite> insert into activity values ('hike',2017,1,1.2345);
sqlite> insert into activity values ('hike',2017,2,3.141592);
sqlite> insert into activity values ('hike',2017,3,-1);
sqlite> insert into activity values ('hike',2017,4,10000);
sqlite> insert into activity values ('run',2017,4,10);
sqlite> insert into activity values ('run',2017,5,100);
sqlite> insert into activity values ('run',2017,6,1000);
```

SQLite is expecting single quotes, and throws the wrong error, it seems.

```
> sequelize.query('SELECT week, SUM (CASE when activityType = "rockclimbing" then elapsedTime else 0 END) AS rockclimbing, SUM (CASE when activityType = "hike" then elapsedTime else 0 END) AS hike, SUM (CASE when activityType = "run" then elapsedTime else 0 END) AS run FROM activity     WHERE year=2017 AND activityType IN ("rockclimbing", "hike", "run") GROUP BY week ORDER BY week', { type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT}).then(function(activities) {console.log(activities)})
Promise {
  _bitField: 0,
  _fulfillmentHandler0: undefined,
  _rejectionHandler0: undefined,
  _promise0: undefined,
  _receiver0: undefined }
> )Executing (default): SELECT week, SUM (CASE when activityType = "rockclimbing" then elapsedTime else 0 END) AS rockclimbing, SUM (CASE when activityType = "hike" then elapsedTime else 0 END) AS hike, SUM (CASE when activityType = "run" then elapsedTime else 0 END) AS run FROM     activity WHERE year=2017 AND activityType IN ("rockclimbing", "hike", "run") GROUP BY week ORDER BY week
Unhandled rejection SequelizeBaseError: SQLITE_ERROR: misuse of aggregate: SUM()
    at Query.formatError (/Users/bryan/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/sqlite/query.js:348:14)
    at afterExecute (/Users/bryan/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/sqlite/query.js:112:29)
    at Statement.errBack (/Users/bryan/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/sqlite3.js:16:21)
```

Comment: Sorry, that's a good catch but it was not my issue. I've edited my question, making sure that the two queries are the same. I still get the same error.

Comment: the `having` clause is for testing post-aggregated values to restrict the result set. since `week` is the attribute that you're grouping by, try putting `week < 53` in the where clause. Is the database engine throwing the error, or the parser in sequelize?

Comment: I removed the `HAVING` clause altogether but still get the same error message from Sequelize. I _believe_ SQLite engine throws this error back to Node/Sequelize. I can see `SQLITE_ERROR: misuse of aggregate: SUM()` as the error message returned inside my `.catch(function(error) {console.log(error)})`

Comment: `misuse of aggregate` is a weird one, can you run any aggregation through sequelize? What's the datatype of elapsedTime?

Comment: I also wonder if the parser that's throwing the error is expecting `SUM(...)` instead of `SUM (...)`

Comment: Just to test simple aggregation I tried `sequelize.query('SELECT AVG(elapsedTime) FROM activity;', {model: Activity})` which returned a small object with `AVG(elapsedTime): 1.12052395209`. So that seems to work. Removing the space after `SUM` had no effect, same issue. The datatype of `elapsedTime` is a float. Perhaps it should be a decimal???

Comment: I might try making sure that you cast the outputs of the case as the same datatype just to be safe, but I doubt that's the problem.

Comment: I cannot _believe_ that single vs double quotes were so important here! Lesson learned!! ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Thanks for all of your time.

Comment: the pleasure is all mine.