# SQLAlchemy: How to filter after aggregation

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

How do I filter out all groups with aggregate share totals of 0?

```
q = session.query(Trades.ticker, func.sum(Trades.shares))
g = q.group_by(Trades.ticker)
f = g.filter(func.sum(Trades.shares) != 0)
result = f.all()
```

This throws the error on line 3:

> ...
> sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) misuse of
> aggregate: sum() ...

A workaround is to remove the filter and use a list comprehension:

```
result = [x for x in g.all() if x[1] != 0.0]
```

But this is very slow compared to filtering a SQL query, because it loads all the data into memory as opposed to only loading the filtered data.

(EDITED to simplify.)

Comment: Somewhat related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/648083/sql-error-misuse-of-aggregate

Answer (score 6):

Okay, the answer is to use [having()](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Query.having). See [related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43756833/2529619).

```
q = session.query(Trades.ticker, func.sum(Trades.shares))
g = q.group_by(Trades.ticker)
f = g.having(func.sum(Trades.shares) != 0)
result = f.all()
```

Nice, simple, and fast.

Writing out the question helped me think it through clearer and helped me find the answer in the documentation. I'm leaving this here in case it helps someone.

(EDITED to reflect revised question.)