# SQL error message Syntax error near where

Tags: sql, debugging

I was trying to write a query that sort out product that had a sale more than $30, but kept getting the error "Error 1: could not prepare statement (1 near "Where": syntax error)"

```
SELECT ProductID, ProductName,SUM(Amount) as SUM
From Products
Group by ProductID, ProductName
Where Sum>=30;
```

Comment: `SELECT` --> `FROM` --> `WHERE` --> `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 1):

`GROUP BY` is supposed to come after `WHERE`.

```
SELECT ProductID, ProductName, SUM(Amount) as SUM 
FROM Products 
WHERE Sum >= 30 
GROUP BY ProductID, ProductName ;
```

Comment: Another error message: could not prepare statement (1 misuse of aggregate: SUM())

Comment: That is probably a separate question. But this may help you understand when and how to use functions like `SUM()` : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/648083/sql-error-misuse-of-aggregate

Answer (score 1):

SELECT ProductID, ProductName, SUM(Amount) as SUM 
FROM Products 
GROUP BY ProductID, ProductName 
having sum(amount)>30;

Answer (score 0):

Use it like this:

```
SELECT ProductID, ProductName,SUM(Amount) as SUM
From Products Where SUM >= 30 Group by ProductID, ProductName;
```

Comment: Thank you. But there is another error message "misuse of aggregate: SUM()"

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, thanks everyone for help!

SELECT ProductID, ProductName, SUM(Price)
FROM Products 
GROUP BY ProductID, ProductName
Having Sum(Price) >= 30